# IE8 is not accepting my privacy policy

Tags: html, cookies, internet-explorer-8

The development version of the site is at http://dev.blueankh.com userid: fix password: demo.

The application is writen in php and the privacy policy is in a header created with the header() function. The site works with firefox but not IE.

When I use fiddler2 it shows the privacy policy on the privacy tab. Since it sees it as a valid, parseable Privacy Policy, I feel it is going out correctly. It also shows the cookies. To me this says the privacy policy is going out correctly in a header.

In IE when I use View -> Webpage Privacy Policy it tells me that based on privacy settings no cookies were blocked. The Cookies column is blank, acknowledging that no cookies were accepted.When I highlight the main page and click summary I get a blank box where the privacy policy should be displayed.

Very frustrating

Comment: You are right that Privacy.php was missing. It was there as privacy.php. This is now fixed but it hasn't resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The link to your privacy policy, Privacy.php, is broken.